# Probability measure over bijection map

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $P$ a probability measure over $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $f: A \rightarrow B$ a bijection from $A$ to $B$ two sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Does the following equality could be hold?
$$
P(f(A)) = P(A).
$$

Thanks,

S

Comment: What about this set : 
$$
A = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n: <x, \omega> \leq \alpha\} \text{ and } B = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n: <\tau x, \omega> \leq \alpha\},
$$
where $\omega \in  \mathbb{R}^n, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, and $\tau > 0$. Here $f(x) = \tau x$.
Thanks

Comment: I did the following: 
\begin{eqnarray*}
P(B)&= P(\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: <\tau x, \omega> \leq \alpha\})\\ 
&=  P(\frac{y}{\tau}\in \mathbb{R}^n: <y, \omega> \leq \alpha\})\\
&=  P({y}{}\in \mathbb{R}^n: <y, \omega> \leq \alpha\})\\
\end{eqnarray*}
If $y \in \mathbb{R}^n, \frac{y}{\tau} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Am I right?

Comment: You should edit your above comments into the question.

Answer (score 3):

No, it does not.

Let $n=1$, and $P$ be such that $P(\{2\})=1$. Let $A=\{2\}$, and let $B=\{1\}$. Let $f(x)=x/2$. Then

$P(f(A))=P(\{1\})=0$. However

$P(A)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

No. We have $f(A)=B$, and since $B$ can have a different measure than $A$ the equality does not hold always.